# Batch Script - Comma causing problems when writing numerical value to txt file

Tags: string, batch-file, scripting, dos, string-concatenation

So this is an example of a script I'm writing to produce txt file containing a list of correctly formatted commands to be passed to another system, based on a long series of questions.

If `objectName`, `objectNumber`, or `objectCategory` are assigned an alphanumeric value, the script will write correctly to the txt file. However, if I were to assign a numerical value, the value is not written to the txt file.

I'm guessing this is a syntax issue related to the use of a comma, as I can replace it with with pretty much anything and the script will behave, though unfortunately it has to be a comma.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET objectCounter=1

SET /p objectName=What is the name of the object %objectCounter%?: 
@ECHO OBJECTNAME%objectCounter%,%objectName%> objects.txt

SET /p objectNumber=How many of object %objectCounter% are there?: 
@ECHO OBJECTNUMBER%objectCounter%,%objectNumber%>> objects.txt

SET /p objectCategory=Which group does object %objectCounter% belong to?: 
@ECHO OBJECTCATEGORY%objectCounter%,%objectNumber%>> objects.txt
```

This is an example of the output to the txt file if `objectNumber` is assigned a value of `1`:

```
OBJECTNAME1,Apple
OBJECTNUMBER1,
OBJECTCATEGORY1,Fruit
```

And this is an example of the output to the txt file if `objectNumber` is assigned a value of `2` or more:

```
OBJECTNAME1,Apple
OBJECTCATEGORY1,Fruit
```

Comment: is this put in a brackets (like in FOR,IF or codeblock)?

Comment: No, nothing like that. Should it be?

Comment: If you're thinking along the lines of using `^,` to escape the comma, I already tried that - no luck.

Comment: Put a space before `>` and `>>`. I believe your %objectNumber% variables are causing an issue with [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), although I'm a little confused as to why you get an ObjectCategory line when objectNumber is 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplification: a `echo` command to send the text `data 1` to a file:

```
 echo data 1>somewhere.txt
```

Here it is easy to see that the `1` will be handled by the parser as the stream number to redirect, not data to send to the file.

But the question is not using a space, but a comma. Why the same behaviour? Because from the parser point of view, **spaces, tabs, commas, semicolons, parenthesis and equals are delimiters**. All these lines fail the same way (tabs omited)

```
echo data 1>>somewhere.txt
echo data,1>>somewhere.txt
echo data;1>>somewhere.txt
echo data=1>>somewhere.txt
echo data(1>>somewhere.txt
echo data)1>>somewhere.txt
```

How to handle it? It is necessary to separate the digit from the redirection, so we can change the order in the line

```
>somewhere.txt echo data,1
```

or force the parser see the separation

```
(echo data,1)>somewhere.txt
```

or, if the data is inside a variable, we can also use delayed expansion

```
set "n=1"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo data,!n!>somewhere.txt
```

Of course, we can also do

```
echo data,1 >>somewhere.txt
```

including a space between the data and the redirection, but the space will be included in the redirected data.

Another option is to reorganize the code

```dos
@ECHO OFF

SET objectCounter=1

SET /p "objectName=What is the name of the object %objectCounter%?: "
SET /p "objectNumber=How many of object %objectCounter% are there?: "
SET /p "objectCategory=Which group does object %objectCounter% belong to?: "

> objects.txt (
    ECHO OBJECTNAME%objectCounter%,%objectName%
    ECHO OBJECTNUMBER%objectCounter%,%objectNumber%
    ECHO OBJECTCATEGORY%objectCounter%,%objectCategory%
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has to do with output redirection in *conjunction* with the comma. I think, with the comma in there, the numeric value is being bound to the redirection rather than to the thing being output.

In other words, while:

```
set x=1
echo xyzzy%x%>qq.txt
```

will work (the thing being output is `xyzzy%x%` with a redirection of `>qq.txt`), the following will not:

```
set x=1
echo xyzzy,%x%>qq.txt
```

(presumably because the thing being output is `xyzzy,` with a redirection operation `1>qq.txt` which is the same as `>qq.txt`). That also explains the difference you're seeing between `1` and other numbers since `1` is standard output.

You can see a similar problem even *without* variable expansion:

```
C:\pax> echo xyzzy1>qq.txt
C:\pax> type qq.txt
xyzzy1

C:\pax> echo xyzzy,1>qq.txt
C:\pax> type qq.txt
xyzzy,
```

One way around it is to reorganise your components so that the numeric value *cannot* be tied to the redirection:

```
>>objects.txt ECHO OBJECTNUMBER%objectCounter%,%objectNumber%
```

I tend to prefer putting them at the start since using something like:

```
echo xyzzy >file
```

will actually output `xyzzy` *and* the space immediately before the `>`.

Modifying the lines like that (and fixing your third `echo` so it outputs the category rather than the number again) gives you:

```
What is the name of the object 1?: Apple
How many of object 1 are there?: 1
Which group does object 1 belong to?: Fruit
```

with the resultant file being:

```
OBJECTNAME1,Apple
OBJECTNUMBER1,1
OBJECTCATEGORY1,Fruit
```